# Уместна ли здесь постановка запятых?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

У него(,) как и у всех остальных(,) хоть и второстепенных героев романа(,) она есть и играет значительную роль.

Answer (score 3):

Все указанные в предложении запятые нужны.

[Сравнительный оборот](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147,4) (Розенталь)

> **3.** Сравнительный оборот с союзом ***как*** выделяется **запятыми** в следующих случаях:
> <...>
> **3)** если сравнительный оборот начинается сочетанием ***как и***: <...> *Дети, **как и взрослые,** должны быть приучены к соблюдению правил общежития.*

[**ХОТЬ**, *союз и частица*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_746) (Грамота.ру)

> **1.** Союз. Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «хоть», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.